# Liquibase error when changeset uses runWith=sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

My environment is SQL Server 2019 and Liquibase 4.8.0

I'm having troubles using runWith=sqlcmd within a changeset. Liquibase responds with:

`Attribute 'runWith' is not allowed to appear in element 'changeSet'`

However, looking at the documentation, and the examples (near the bottom), here:
https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/using-sqlcmd-integration.html

...it seems to be saying that the "runWith" attribute ***should*** be within the changeSet tag

**liquibase.properties**

```
classpath=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\sqljdbc_10.2\\enu\\mssql-jdbc-10.2.0.jre8.jar
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=SSReporting;Enlist=false
liquibaseSchemaName=dbo
username=deploy_dbbuild
password=xxxxxxx
changeLogFile=changelog.xml
liquibase.hub.mode=off
integratedSecurity=false
liquibase.sqlcmd.args=-v db_to_use=SSReporting
liquibase.sqlcmd.keep.temp=true
liquibase.sqlcmd.keep.temp.name=liq.log
liquibase.sqlcmd.path=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn
liquibase.sqlcmd.timeout=-1
```

**changelog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd" >

        <changeSet id="sqlcmd_test" runWith="sqlcmd" runOnChange="true" author="smcintosh" >
                <sqlFile path="sqlcmd_test.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
        </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Check that sqlcmd is where I think it is:

```
C:\> where sqlcmd
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
```

**sqlcmd_test.sql**

```
DECLARE @foobat int;
GO
```

Trying it out...

````
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 13:53:48 (version 4.8.0 #1581 built at 2022-02-18 21:43+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.8.0
Liquibase Pro 4.8.0 by Liquibase licensed to Liquibase Pro Evaluation until Tue Mar 29 19:00:00 EDT 2022
WARNING!  Your license will expire in 5 days!
To renew Liquibase Pro please contact sales@liquibase.com or go to https://www.liquibase.org/download

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error parsing line 8 column 86 of changelog.xml: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'runWith' is not allowed to appear in element 'changeSet'.

For more information, please use the --log-level flag```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that you are pointing to out of date XSD files in the header of your XML Changelog file. You are pointing to some marked version 2.0 - which are super old and predate the  capability.

At any point, the correct ones are in the **examples** folder under your Liquibase installation.

For reference, as of 4.8.0, the header in the example is:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.6.xsd
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.6.xsd ">
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked; you are a life saver. Sometimes I get myself into so much trouble cutting and pasting from the wrong places.